# Angular - How to resolve Http failure response for third party API

Tags: angular

In Angular-14 project, I have this third party api:

> https://thirtpartyapi.com/AccountDetail?accountNumber

which appears this way:

```
{
    "AccountNumber": "0987654321",
    "CustomerName": "Frank Akwetey"
}
```

**accountNumber** is the parameter

The third party API is secured with these headers:

headers:

```
"secId": "knt10", 
"secName": "kkcm", 
"secPassword": "nnkml"
```

What I want to achieve is that when the user enters data into AccountNumber into the textinput field, the application should validate using the third party api, and also display the CustomerName of the corresponding AccountNumber in a label under the accountNumber textinput field.

So I have this Angular code:

Service:

```
private readonly accountBaseURL!: string;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router
    ) {
      this.accountBaseURL ="https://thirtpartyapi.com/";
    }

    getAccountDetail(accountNumber: string){
      let header = new HttpHeaders();
      header.append('Content-Type', 'applications/json');
      header.append('secId', 'knt10');
      header.append('secName', 'kkcm');
      header.append('secPassword', 'nnkml');
      return this.http.get(this.accountBaseURL + "AccountDetail?accountNumber="+ accountNumber, { headers: header})
  }
```

component.ts:

```
accountValue!: string;
allAccountDetail: any[] = [];

  onAccountNumberSearch() {
    this.accountValue = this.createAccountForm.value.accountNumber;
    console.log(this.accountValue);
    if (this.accountValue.length === 10) {
      this.accountService.getAccountDetail(this.accountValue).subscribe({
        next: (res: any) => {
          this.allAccountDetail = res;
          console.log(this.allAccountDetail);
          this.isLoading = false;
        },
        error: (error) => {
          this.toastr.error(error.message);
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

component.html:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="accountNumber">Account Number<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName='accountNumber'
    id="accountNumber"
    (input)="onAccountNumberSearch()"
    placeholder="Account Number">
</div>
```

When User enters data:

> console.log(this.accountValue) gives 0987654321

which is correct, but I got this errors:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://thirtpartyapi.com/AccountDetail?accountNumber=0987654321' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

> Http failure response for https://thirtpartyapi.com/AccountDetail?accountNumber=0987654321

> Caller credential cannot be empty

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your third party is callable from a web application? You can maybe disable the CORS protection for your own browser temporarily but only yours. This is something the third party API has to fix, not you.

Comment: Yes, it is callable @Arcord. I have used it before in ASP.NET Core Web API.   Just that this time around, it is coming directly into Angular and not from .NET Core.    Or could it be the way, I added the three (3) headers?

Comment: CORS errors aren't handled by angular, since it is a pre-flight request. IF you have control over the thirdparty api, allow the angular url to request it, otherwise, in development you could use a proxy See https://angular.io/guide/build on the proxy section

Comment: CORS is a security mechanism ensured by the browser. The communication between ASP.NET Core Web API and the third party API is not impacted since there is no browser in between. But if you call the third party API from your Angular app there is of course a browser involved... You can use a proxy as suggested by Caio but if you have already your own API I would suggest to contact it and to let it contact the third party API. Maybe the third party API is not designed to be contacted directly from the browser or maybe you need to contact them to be whitelisted?